# ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property 0 not found on String and there is no default value

Tags: actionscript

He,everyone. I'm new in ActionScript 3 and I don't understand where is my mistake.

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    button = new Sprite();
    button.name = String.fromCharCode(65 + i);
    button.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x000000);
    button.graphics.beginFill(0x00FF00);
    button.graphics.drawRect( Keyboard_Container.x + i * ButtonSize,Keyboard_Container.y,ButtonSize,ButtonSize );
    button.graphics.endFill();
    button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,InitLetter);
    Keyboard_Container.addChild(button);
}
```

And the InitLetter function from event listener is

```
private function InitLetter(event:MouseEvent):void {
    this.letter = event.target.name;
}
```

The error that I received is "ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property 0 not found on String and there is no default value."

Why I cannot gain access name of button trough event.target. Why? Thank you very much.

Comment: Your code looks fine, but I don't know what you have in your stage and when / how you got that error. Try to use `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target`, if the problem persist, try to put more details.

Comment: I tried but unsuccessful.
Im making Hangman
http://pastebin.com/33jC2gQW -> This is my Hangman class(may be the problem) and 
http://pastebin.com/Qg0s12Zw -> is my Keyboard class(i think it is the problem)

And the whole content of error is ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property 0 not found on String and there is no default value.
 at Hangman/CheckLetter()
 at Hangman/PlayGame()
 at Function/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::apply()
 at SetIntervalTimer/onTimer()
 at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
 at flash.utils::Timer/tick()

Thank you,akmozo!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your main Hangman class, in the `CheckLetter()` function :

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < word.length; i++)
{
    if (word[i] == currentLetter)       // word is a String and not an Array
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Here you should know that to get a char from a String, we use [`string.charAt(i)`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#charAt()), if you want to use an Array object, you can do :

```
word:Array = "word".split("");     // gives : ["w", "o", "r", "d"]
```

Also, I don't know why you are using this : [`setInterval(PlayGame,100);`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#setInterval()), normally you can check the word just when the user put a new letter and not every 100 ms ! and even you have to use it ( in another case ), it's better to use a [`Timer`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html) or just `Event.ENTER_FRAME` ...

Hope that can help.